# Populating Custom ArrayAdapters

Tags: java, android, oop

I have made my own CustomArrayAdapter to show list of Brazilian Restaurants.  I have overidden the GetView method to make my own custom view.

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] strings) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,false);
     String [] items= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations_array);
     TextView tv= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
     tv.setText(items[position]);
     iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.brazil);
            return row;
        }
    }
```

Currently this new GetView class is pulling in a text string from a resource xml file and putting it into the list item.

1. If I wanted to incorporate an array of extra data generated within the app, I assume that I don't do the array generating in the GetView class as this will be recreated  each time a new row is made.
2. Where do I put the code to make the array, and how do I call this data into the GetView code above?

Answer (score 1):

It's worth pointing out that for better performance you should be making use of the `convertView` variable passed into the `getView()` method.

The use of `convertView` allows you to re-use list item views instead of creating new ones which has a heavy performance hit. If you have a large data set or value performance in your app, you would do well to check out the [documentation for `getView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

Your code would then look something more like this:

```
...
//it's also worth moving these methods to your constructor so they aren't called every time getView() for better performance
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
String [] items= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations_array);

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    TextView tv= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    tv.setText(items[position]);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.brazil);
    return row;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @CodeDownZero's answer, I *highly* recommend you adopt the [ViewHolder](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#ownadapter_viewHolder) pattern, and **definitely** recycle your listviews (using `convertview`).

```
...

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = null;
  if (convertView == null) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(textViewResourceId, parent, false);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    viewHolder.tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);

  } else {
    view = convertView;
  }

  ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

  MyDataClass data = this.getItem(position);
  holder.tv1.setText(data.street);
  holder.tv2.setText(data.name);
  return view;
}

...

private class ViewHolder {
  private TextView tv1;
  private TextView tv2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can base an ArrayAdapter on a custom class instead of string. Here is an example:

```
public class MyDataClass {
  public String street;
  public String name;
}
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyDataClass> {
        @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,false);
     TextView tv1= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     TextView tv2= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     MyDataClass data = this.getItem(position);
     tv1.setText(data.street);
     tv2.setText(data.name);
     return row;
   }
}
```

To populate the Adapter with data you can use this snippet in the OnCreate method of the Activity:

```
  ..
  MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
  MyDataClass lData = new MyDataClass();  // here was a mistake
  lData.name = "MyName";
  lData.street = "MyRoad";
  adapter.Add(lData);
  ..
  ListView.Adapter=adapter; // where Listview is the Listview
```

Comment: Hi when I try this solution- I get a message that new lData cannot be resolved to a type!

Comment: Yes there is a mistake in the line containing MyDataClass lData = new lData(); - just edited it